# How Bitwise AND "&" Works Logically?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

i need to understand a bit of code please from any one have experience with operators, i have an open source code and i need to understand this part:

```
public static bool ContainsDestroyWholeRowColumn(BonusType bt)
{
    return (bt & BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn) 
        == BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn;
}
```

and BonusType is an enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum BonusType
{
    None,
    DestroyWholeRowColumn
}
```

Please, Explain how this part works ?

**return (bt & BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn) 
            == BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn;**

why not write : **return bt == BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn;** ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Either someone is hot-dogging the code, or there was/will be more values in the enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[TestClass]
public class EnumTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void FlagsTest()
    {
        var test1 = BonusType.None;
        Assert.That(ContainsDestroyWholeRowColumn(test1), Is.False);
        var test2 = BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn;
        Assert.That(ContainsDestroyWholeRowColumn(test2));
        var test3 = BonusType.None | BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn;
        Assert.That(ContainsDestroyWholeRowColumn(test3));

        Assert.That(test3 == BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn);

        Assert.That(ContainsDestroyWholeRowColumn((BonusType)5));
    }

}

[Flags]
public enum BonusType
{
    None,
    DestroyWholeRowColumn
}

public static bool ContainsDestroyWholeRowColumn(BonusType bt)
{
    return (bt & BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn)
        == BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn;
}
```

As you can see in this example, the only case for when the behavior would be different than the equality operator is if an `int` is cast to `BonusType`.

It is also possible that the == operator could be overloaded for BonusType which could change the expected behavior.

Both of these are very, very bad things to do (IMO).

Comment: Thanks for this useful information :)
i tested it in the two conditions and the results are equal!

Answer (score 1):

`bt` is (likely) a bit string in this case. The operation of `AND`ing it with a constant and then comparing is called masking.

Here's an example. We'll use permissions. Say

```
read =    001
write =   010
execute = 111
```

So suppose a user has permissions on a particular file, and we want to test if they can, say, write to it.

```
userPermissions = 011
```

If we simply check `userPermissions == write` that's clearly false, as `011 != 010`. However

```
userPermissions & write = 010 = write
```

And if instead the user had

```
userPermissions = 101
```

Then

```
 userPermissions & write = 000 != write
```

So, you can see how this allows data to be stored as bitstrings, and then "masked" to see if it has a particular bit set or not.

The takeaway really is that for any bitstrings `b` and `a` if `a` has exactly one bit set, then `b&a` will either be `a` or `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
In & or && Both are doing AND operation but behaviour is very different when you try to compare with'&' then if first is true or not it's doesn't effect on it and always it goes to second statement and set it value like if(a==b & a=b) it's always goes to the second statement but when you use '&&' operator like if(a==b && a=b) in that case if first condition is true hen only give to the second statement .and the same thing happening in your condition also .
But you can compare bt == BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn but because you are comparing enum value which is basically taking int value .if you want to know some more in detail so follow this program do some r&d on it.basically '&' or '|' this operator work on binary format.
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BonusType bt=(BonusType)1;
            Console.WriteLine(ContainsDestroyWholeRowColumn(bt));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static bool ContainsDestroyWholeRowColumn(BonusType bt)
        {
            return (bt == BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn);
               // == BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn;
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum BonusType
    {
        None=1,
        DestroyWholeRowColumn=0,
        abc,
        xyz
    }
```

may be it will help for you thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, bt is probably a bit field, containing multiple flag values.

Here, they want to check just one bit of bt, and ignore the rest.

The expression

```
  bt == BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn
```

would return false if both the DestroyWholeRowColumn and any other flag in bt was true, which is not what they want.

Comment: in the specific case given, it wouldn't make a difference. Both `bt = BonusType.None` and `bt = BonusType.None | BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn` would satisfy `bt == BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn`